# How to remove a model which has been inserted in a Ros-enabled plugin?

Tags: gazebo-model, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I have a difficulty to remove a model during the simulation time. I have inserted this light point using InsertModelSDF() method in a callback function that is run every time data is published to ros topic.

To be clear more , the below code is the callback function:

void ROSCallback_Vel(const geometry_msgs::Twist::ConstPtr& msg)

```
{
```

this->simtime = common::Time(0.90);

if ( this->model2_ ->GetWorld()->GetSimTime() > this->simtime )

{

sdf::SDF sphereSDF;

```
sphereSDF.SetFromString(
   "<sdf version ='1.4'>\
     <light type='Point' name='bulb100'>\
       <pose>-2.0 -0.994333 0.8  0 0 0</pose>\
    <diffuse>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</diffuse>\
     <specular>.4 .4 .4 0</specular>\
     <attenuation>\
            <range>2</range>\
            <linear>0.0</linear>\
            <constant>0.1</constant>\
            <quadratic>0.5</quadratic>\
      </attenuation>\
        <direction>0.0 0.7 0.0</direction>\
        <cast_shadows>false</cast_shadows>\
       </light>\
    </sdf>");
```

this->model2_ ->GetWorld()->InsertModelSDF(sphereSDF);
}

ROS_INFO("subscriber two velocities: [%f %f %f %f %f %f ]", msg->linear.x,msg->linear.y,msg->linear.z,
msg->angular.x,msg->angular.y, msg->angular.z);

```
        Vlinx=msg->linear.x; Vliny=msg->linear.y; Vlinz=msg->linear.z;
        Vangx=msg->angular.x; Vangy=msg->angular.y; Vangz=msg->angular.z;
       this->model_->SetLinearVel(math::Vector3( Vlinx, Vliny, Vlinz));
       this->model_->SetAngularVel(math::Vector3(Vangx, Vangy, Vangz));

}
```

my question is:

Is there a way to remove this light point using gazebo functions or maybe other ways to do that?
Any ideas and suggestions are appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2678/how-to-remove-a-model-which-has-been-inserted-in-a-ros-enabled-plugin??/) by [Zahra](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/320/zahra/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 122 on 2013-05-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can send a request message to delete the light

[gzfactory's delete function](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/096ec69b95bea437126f3b5acfaf0e6af1865d25/tools/gzfactory.cc?at=default#cl-129) shows how to send the message

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2013-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0